# data grouping in pandas for dataFrame have same row value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have csv file in below format

```
10  1
20  2
30  3
40  4
50  5
10  6
20  7
30  8
40  9
50  10
10  11
20  12
30  13
40  14
50  15
```

Here col1 is input and col2 is output. I want this data to be transformed into something like this

```
10  1   6  11
20  2   7  12
30  3   8  13
40  4   9  14
50  5  10  15
```

how can I do this using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need create groups by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for new columns names and then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['a', df.groupby('a').cumcount()])['b'].unstack()
print (df)
    0   1   2
a            
10  1   6  11
20  2   7  12
30  3   8  13
40  4   9  14
50  5  10  15
```

For dictionary use [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), but swap values in `set_index`:

```
d = df.set_index([df.groupby('a').cumcount(), 'a'])['b'].unstack().to_dict('l')
print (d)

{40: [4, 9, 14], 10: [1, 6, 11], 20: [2, 7, 12], 50: [5, 10, 15], 30: [3, 8, 13]}
```

Detail:

```
print (df.groupby('a').cumcount())
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    2
11    2
12    2
13    2
14    2
dtype: int64
```

Setup:

```
print (df)
     a   b
0   10   1
1   20   2
2   30   3
3   40   4
4   50   5
5   10   6
6   20   7
7   30   8
8   40   9
9   50  10
10  10  11
11  20  12
12  30  13
13  40  14
14  50  15
```

Comment: how can i make an array like { 10:  1   6  11}  in this case? I need to do it for all of them and then compute a confidence interval , I will find CI but please tell me how to do transformation

Comment: Do you need column from first `a` index for `4` columns? Or create `dictionary` like `{40: [4, 9, 14], 10: [1, 6, 11], 20: [2, 7, 12], 50: [5, 10, 15], 30: [3, 8, 13]}` ?

Comment: Yes, I need it in form of Dictionary